# Hidden Markov Model (HMM) vs Maximum Entropy Markov Model (MEMM)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, hidden-markov-models, part-of-speech

what are the advantages and the weakness of both systems in the Part of Speech tagging? Since the HMM use an accurate formula to calculate the likelihood and the probability that a certain tag appears, can it be considerate more efficient?